# How to disable form while loading panel shows by p:ajaxstatus

Tags: primefaces

I would like to disable form selection while loading panel appears. I have been using `p:ajaxstatus` for loading panel

Comment: Did you check the PrimeFaces showcase for components that might be useful?

Comment: @Kukeltje I did it .Thanks for responding

Comment: you did what? Check the showcase? Now or Before? Found a solution?

Comment: @Kukeltje <p:ajaxStatus style="width:32px;height:32px;position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;display:block;z-index:1004;" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()">
                 
                </p:ajaxStatus>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"
     closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
     <p:graphicImage name="images/preloader.gif" library="modena-layout" />
    </p:dialog>

Comment: Then either post this as an answer or remove the question. (`p:blockUI` is what I use a lot)

Comment: @Kukeltje if i go with p:blockUI i need to mention block id but with this following answer no need to do like that

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:ajaxStatus style="width:32px;height:32px;position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;display:block;z-in‌​dex:1004;" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()"> 
</p:ajaxStatus>
<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false"> <p:graphicImage name="images/preloader.gif" library="modena-layout" />
</p:dialog>
```